# Read from XML selecting by multiple attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

How do I query for this particular XML result to obtain all values for `Flow sensor="DUT" unit="adc" testpoint="1"` from below in SQL Server?

```
<Phitrics>
  <TestResults>
    <ParametricData>
      <CalibrationDiagnostic>
        <Flow sensor="DUT" unit="adc" testpoint="0">0</Flow>
        <Flow sensor="Cal" unit="L/min" testpoint="0">0.0</Flow>
        <Flow sensor="DUT" unit="adc" testpoint="1">24</Flow>
        <Flow sensor="Cal" unit="L/min" testpoint="1">1.9</Flow>
        <Flow sensor="DUT" unit="adc" testpoint="2">41</Flow>
      </CalibrationDiagnostic>
    </ParametricData>
  </TestResults>
</Phitrics>
```

I have tried;

```
SELECT XmlResults.value('data(/Phitrics/TestResults/ParametricData/CalibrationDiagnostic/Flow sensor="DUT" unit="adc" testpoint="1"/text())[1]', 'varchar(10)')    
FROM table
```

But I get the following error:

> XQuery [ResultsTbl.XmlResults.value()]: ',' or ')' expected

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello Dale, just managed to check. Your solution works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing:

1. Square brackets (`[]`) around the attribute match conditions
2. Prefixing the attribute names with '@'
3. Adding each match condition separately

```sql
select XmlResults.value('data(/Phitrics/TestResults/ParametricData/CalibrationDiagnostic/Flow[@sensor="DUT"][@unit="adc"][@testpoint="1"]/text())[1]', 'varchar(10)')
from Table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @xml XML
set @xml = 
'<Phitrics>
 <TestResults>
  <ParametricData>
   <CalibrationDiagnostic>
    <Flow sensor="DUT" unit="adc" testpoint="0">0</Flow>
    <Flow sensor="Cal" unit="L/min" testpoint="0">0.0</Flow>
    <Flow sensor="DUT" unit="adc" testpoint="1">24</Flow>
    <Flow sensor="Cal" unit="L/min" testpoint="1">1.9</Flow>
    <Flow sensor="DUT" unit="adc" testpoint="2">41</Flow>
   </CalibrationDiagnostic>
   </ParametricData>
  </TestResults>
 </Phitrics>'

select 
 a.value('@sensor', 'varchar') as Sensor,
 a.value('@unit', 'varchar') as Unit,
 a.value('@testpoint', 'varchar') as Testpoint
from @xml.nodes('/Phitrics/TestResults/ParametricData/CalibrationDiagnostic/Flow') as b(a)
```